# Automate downloading of transaction details from Authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

Has anybody had any luck in automatically downloading the daily transaction details from Authorize.net?

Right now we have to use the "Search" function, enter a date range, select the format, download, then Import.

Frustratingly, they do not have an API for this function.

Are there any tools or alternative approaches that you have implemented for downloading this daily detail?

Answer (score 1):

They have a [reporting API](http://www.authorize.net/support/ReportingGuide_XML.pdf) you can use. Just set up a cron job that gets the transactions for each day using the [getTransactionsList() API call](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/News-and-Announcements/New-API-Call-getTransactionList/td-p/6772) and you're all set.

Comment: GREAT! Looks like they just added this in September.  I've been waiting for this for years!